# Why my stored procedure return "?" on insert or return empty in select statement in UTF-8

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have several procedure with VARCHAR parameters as input, when i upload a new database to my server, i have a problem with VARCHAR parameters as input.

That stored procedure changed string to `?` (question sing)

For example i have this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_insert`(
IN _title VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `myTable` SET `title` = _title
;END//
```

This query probably works like this:

> INSERT INTO `myTable` SET `title` = '???'

Why this problem occur?

Comment: I create the SP and it works for me, even the insert was perfect, so the error should be in your connection or in your Mysql Version

Comment: @jcho360 I answer my own question. in title i said in `UTF8` language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occur when my database was not utf8 collation before i import any data if you are using utf8 data in your text.

I hade to note that to remember this 3 steps for utf8 database:

1. Connection must be "SET NAMES UTF8"
2. Database had to set UTF8 collation and then import data or insert any record
3. All tables and varchar field have to set UTF8 collation